# VBA for Autocomplete ComboBox from another closed workbook

Tags: excel, combobox, excel-2013, vba

I am getting problem in writting VBA for my combobox in userform.
What I want with my combobox to do is..

1. I want to select list of my items from another closed workbook. (Another
   workbooks address = "E:\AtirsPsyche\BMark\Data") (list Range =
   "C8:C)(Sheet name  = Customer)
2. I want auto complete in my
   ComboBox.
3. I want ComboBox to show item names in aplhabatical
   order list as I write starting word of my item in ComboBox.
4. ComboBox should show the added items in that other closed workbook's list.
   Because that list is addable.
5. I don't want ComboBox to show empty
   list.(i.e. if I have 3 items in my list and the range of list is 100
   rows the it shouldn't show empty list after 3 items in my list)
   Here my VBA is

   Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Invoice")
    sh.Range("J14").Value = Me.ComboBox1.Value
   End Sub

   Private Sub Userform_Initialize()
      With GetObject("E:\AtirsPsyche\BMark\Data.xlsm")
         ComboBox1.List = .Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C8:C65536").Value
         .Close 0
      End With
   End Sub

I am getting unknown errors and bugs.
Please send me the VBA for this userform.
I also have command button in my user form which is going to show my selected item in certain column of same sheet. So if you send me VBA for this also, then that would be more appriciated. (cell name where my combobox selected value should appear = "(E$7$:G$7$"))
Thanks a lot in advance.
S. Atir.

Comment: Hi. You're unlikely to get someone just writing your code for you. You've explained very clearly what your expected results are, but you've not shown what you've done to get there yourself and not shown us what the problems with it are. With those things in your question, you'll get a *lot* more help.

Comment: Sorry for that, I didn't know it then that I am suppose to attach it with my question.

Comment: Now I've attached it. You can see it. Thanks